# Kubectl apply does not update pods or deployments

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I'm using a CI to update my kubernetes cluster whenever there's an update to an image. Whenever the image is pushed and has the latest tag it kubectl apply's the existing deployment but nothing gets updated.

this is what runs
`$ kubectl apply --record --filename /tmp/deployment.yaml`

My goal is when the apply is ran that a rolling deployment gets executed.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: api
spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
    metadata:
        labels:
        app: api
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: api
        image: us.gcr.io/joule-eed41/api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
            - containerPort: 1337
        args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - echo running api;npm start
        env:        
        - name: NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: config
                key: NAMESPACE
```

Comment: What's in your YAML file?

Comment: @kichik added the yaml

Comment: the issue is that k8s doesn't know that actual image tagged changed. you have 2 solutions: 1) remove existing pods, then new version will be pulled 2) use new version each time.

Comment: @uthark what do you mean by use the new version each time?

Comment: @HannanRhodes your docker image should be published under strict version, not floating `latest`. e.g. 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc.

Comment: @uthark ok, but how would i deploy it if my YAML stays the same? would i have to create a dynamic yaml?

Comment: Either update yaml with a correct version OR, as just delete pods with the current version. k8s will try to recreate them and since you set imagePullPolicy to always, it will try to fetch `latest`.

Comment: Yes, you should update your `image:`  with the correct tag every time. If you're working locally on Minikube, you can utilize `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` and restart the pod to pick up a newer image that's just reuploaded to the same tag, so you won't need to modify the YAML again.

Answer (score 2):

As @ksholla20 mentionedm using `kubectl set image` is a good option for many (most?) cases.

But if you can't change the image tag consider using:

1 ) `kubectl rollout restart deployment/<name>`
([reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-restart-em-)).

2 )  `kubectl patch deployment <name> -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"version\":\"$CURRENT_BUILD_HASH_OR_DATE\"}}}}}}"` ([reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch))

(*) Notice that the `patch` command allow you to change specific properties in the deployment (or any other object chosen) like the *label selector* and the *pod label* or other properties like the value of the `NAMESPACE` environment variable in your example.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, have a specific tag.
Set new image using following command

kubectl set image deployment/deployment_name deployment_name=image_name:image_tag

In your case it would be

kubectl set image deployment/api   api=us.gcr.io/joule-eed41/api:0.1

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem and none of the solutions posted so far will help.  The solution is easy, but not easy to see or predict. The applied yaml will generate both a deployment and a replicaset the first time it's run. Unfortunately, applying changes to the manifest likely only replaces the replicaset, while the deployment will remain unchanged. This is a problem because some changes need to happen at the deployment level, but the old deployment hangs around. To have best results, delete the deployment and ensure all previous deployments and replicasets are deleted. Then apply the updated manifest.